# cURL linking error “unresolved external symbol _Curl_base64_enode”

Tags: c, visual-studio, curl, libcurl

Facing these linker errors while trying to build libcurl from source on Windows Visual Studio

```
1>digest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
_Curl_base64_encode 1>http.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Curl_base64_encode 1>ntlm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Curl_base64_encode 1>cram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_base64_decode referenced in function
_Curl_auth_decode_cram_md5_message 1>digest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Curl_base64_decode 1>ntlm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Curl_base64_decode 1>cram.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Curl_HMAC_MD5 1>curl_ntlm_core.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
_Curl_HMAC_MD5 1>curl_ntlm_core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_md4it referenced in function
_Curl_ntlm_core_mk_nt_hash 1>digest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_md5it referenced in function
_Curl_auth_create_digest_http_message 1>ntlm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Curl_md5it 1>digest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_MD5_init referenced in function
_Curl_auth_create_digest_md5_message 1>digest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_MD5_update referenced in function
_Curl_auth_create_digest_md5_message 1>digest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_MD5_final referenced in function
_Curl_auth_create_digest_md5_message 1>digest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_sha256it referenced in function
_Curl_auth_create_digest_http_message 1>digest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Curl_DIGEST_MD5 1>doh.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Curl_base64url_encode referenced in function _dohprobe 1>tool_help.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_version referenced in function
_tool_version_info 1>tool_writeout_json.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_version 1>tool_libinfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_version_info referenced in function _get_libcurl_info 1>tool_paramhlp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_version_info
```

Comment: Hi , can you put your code in post for understanding what's happened

Comment: Hi, i got the error fixed : it was a silly mistake from my side : i did not notice that i had few files with same name, because of that the later files were ignored by visual studio and this eventually led to these errors.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake from my side : i did not notice that i had few files with same name, because of that the later files were ignored by visual studio and this eventually led to these errors.